# Best Practice on storing WCF Binding paremeters to be shared by both proxies and WCF Services?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, configuration

I am currently coding a set of helper classes to be used when creating a proxy client[for Client/Silverlight use] for consuming  WCF services on the Server (NOT using Add Service Reference).

Notice how I am setting up the buffer size to the max allowed (on the first code snippet), because for some services we have some big payload requirements. The secundary effect is that now, I have to setup the WCF service to share the same buffer size with the proxy client, so that they are in sync. I don't want to have to enter these numbers in a configuration file (one on the client, one on the server); instead I want to share some kind of configuration object for both, so that I only change the settings once.

My initial idea is creating a static class with static readonly fields as configuration items, to provide easy access to each configuration set, as well as intellisense integration. Any thoughts or recommendations?

```
// .... First code snippet
        BasicHttpBinaryBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinaryBinding ();

        // Increase the buffer sizes to the limit
        binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;  // <------- HARD CODED
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue; // <------- HARD CODED

        EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(
            string.Format ( "{0}{1}", _baseUri, string.Format ( BASE_SERVICE,       serviceName ) ) );
```

//......................

/*
CONFIGURATION CLASSES
*/

```
public class BindingBufferConfiguration
{
    public int MaxBufferSize { get; protected set;}
    public int MaxReceivedMessageSize { get; protected set; }

    public BindingBufferConfiguration (int MaxBufferSize,int MaxReceivedMessageSize)
    {
        this.MaxBufferSize = MaxBufferSize;
        this.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxReceivedMessageSize;
    }
}

 public static class PatientModuleBufferConfiguration
{
     public static readonly BindingBufferConfiguration PatientProxyBufferConfiguration = new BindingBufferConfiguration ( 4096, 4096 );
     public static readonly BindingBufferConfiguration PatientPhotoProxyBufferConfiguration = new BindingBufferConfiguration(1024 * 500 /*500 KB*/,1024 * 500 /*500 KB*/ )
     // ....
}
```

---

Either no one really has a good answer to the question, or there is no right answer. In my case, this has been working for 3 motnhs and no issues so far.

I am marking the question as answered.